Issue changing Behavior Tree in Nav2
I am trying to follow this tutorial for NAV2 to begin development of dynamic object following. I got everything running however I am not quite sure that I properly changed the behavior tree. I haven't found a way to verify if the right BT file is being loaded. And when I click on the publish point button in rvizz, it doesn't seem to do anything. In the rqt_graph it shows that the /clicked_point_to_pose topic is being properly converted to /goal_update but it isn't being utilized by the bt_navigator node.
For further clarification, in this post someone had the exact same issue as me.
I think it may be a path issue, but I am unsure first off what the correct tag is in the yaml file, or how to set the path of the bt to be used from the launch file (navigation_launch.py). From reading around online, this is apparently how one goes about changing the bt.
Basically, if someone could show me exactly what I need to write in the launch file or in nav2_params.yaml to do this, it would help me out a lot.
